# Dell Insipron 15z Lubuntu 22.04 LTS No Wifi

Tags: lubuntu

Dell Inspiron laptop running Windows 10. Lubuntu 22.04 LTS not installed; running it from a flash drive.  I am able to connect to internet with an ethernet cable, but Wifi not recognized by Lubuntu.  Wifi works fine in Windows 10.  Command lspci, along with other info, gave the following:  Network controller:  Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4312 802.11 b/g LP-PHY (rev 01).  Thanks in advance for help with this problem.